# AWS Endpoint that is reachable from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am confused about setting up an AWS endpoint.

Requirements:

HTTP / HTTPS requests sent to endpoint should be successful only if
-the IP address the request is coming from is part of my on-premises network (I have a VPN connecting my on premises network and VPC)

Browser requests coming from IP addresses not part of my on-premises network should be denied. I have set up an application load balancer in a public subnet. The Endpoint is private and in a public subnet. I am having trouble routing traffic so that traffic reaches the endpoint through the load balancer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the "endpoint" you mention? Is it the Load Balancer, or an API Gateway endpoint, or a back-end server? How have you configured the "endpoint" to be private? Is your problem sending traffic via the VPN to the Load Balancer, or is the problem sending traffic from the Load Balancer to the 'endpoint'? Please Edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: The endpoint is a private VPC endpoint. My issue is sending traffic through browser request to the private VPC endpoint. SSHing into the public subnet instance and calling the VPC endpoint results in successful responses, but I am trying to avoid SSH and call the requests by entering them into a web search browser. I believe that I am having trouble routing traffic from Internet gateway all the way to the private VPC endpoint. I do not know what inbound and outbound rules to use for each step (Network ACL, Security group, application load balancer / target).